# Problems Intel Upgrading in Trusty

Tags: upgrade, intel-graphics

I am wondering how do I upgrade an Intel card. This card is harder than any card.

I've tried the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` but when I install it says:

```
diamond@945GCMX-S2:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo: unable to resolve host 945GCMX-S2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-14
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.2.901-2ubuntu4~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

diamond@945GCMX-S2:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo: unable to resolve host 945GCMX-S2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas indicator-sound libfs6 libllvm3.4 x11-apps
  x11-session-utils x11-xfs-utils xinit
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xorg xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-utopic xubuntu-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 30 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,338 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I've also tried `sgfxi` but after I tried it broke my computer (boot into GRUB, then found the screen black.)

In Intel Graphics Updater (01.org) it says Unsupported Version, Distro or something like that...

And for note, I AM running Xubuntu 14.10.4 Trusty Tahr on `e17` Desktop Environment.

P/S: It doesn't show anything about my graphic card in `hardinfo`

Edit: I've bought an nVidia 220 and now I can't install `nvidia-331`! All because of the `xserver-xorg-core` and `xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic`